# Understanding decode stage of x86 fetch-decode-execute pipeline and its (lack of) register requirements

Tags: computer-architecture, decoder, rtl, x86, pipeline

FDE pipeline has register requirements for the F & D stages: For fetching an instruction from memory, the instruction pointer register points to the memory location of the next instruction to be executed. For execute stage, the GPRs are used.

For the decode stage- it is just an opcode decoder block which is RTL that functions to decode an opcode into the following:

- corresponding instruction to be executed
- the operands to be used
- registers used for the same in the execute phase
  So because it is a piece of hardcoded logic for a given ISA, it doesn't require its own registers unlike the other two pipeline stages, right? It just passes on what it has decoded to the execute stage.

Do let me know if this understanding of mine is accurate.

Comment: Are you talking about the original 8088? Or about the post-P II system with re-order buffer (RISC instructions), registration stations (for access to functional units like the ALU), retire units, etc? Or?

Answer (score 2):

As with many things in computing, there is the theoretical background and the shortcuts taken in the actual implementation.

You can model pretty much any CPU as a state machine that goes through distinct phases sequentially, then you have your classic fetch-decode-execute. I've [done that](https://github.com/Backseating-Committee-2k/vhdl/blob/main/logic/cpu/cpu_sequential.vhdl) for a fantasy architecture once, it works and is somewhat easy to read. It is also slow and uses more logic resources than necessary.

Real world CPU designs will deviate quite a bit from the theoretical model, and this is especially true of x86, where the original design is really old, new use cases have been grafted on several times and the execution completely redesigned without changing the instruction set.

The word "register" also has multiple meanings here, because it is used both at the low level for any storage element, and at the high level for storage addressible by specific instructions in the platform ISA.

So if the decode stage has "registers", these aren't user visible. When an ISA requires accurate decoding to take multiple cycles, then the decode unit will need to be a small state machine, and that state will need to be kept somewhere, and the low level people will also call this a "register."

For example, the "rep" prefixes that repeat an instruction are stateful, because instruction fetch pauses until the repetition is complete. Depending on the implementation, some other instructions can also be split into simpler instructions during decoding -- a "call" instruction consists of "store" and a "jump", and a complex indexed addressing mode can be implemented as "shift" and "add" instructions.